# Button OnClickListener giving ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN error

Tags: java, android, button, onclicklistener

I'm trying to create a simple Android program. I've created an activity and added just one button on which I've set up an OnclickListener to print "Hello World" in the log, a simple task. But whenever I run the app, every time I click the button, I get the error "ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN".

I've tried to put my layout inside a FragmentLayout, or build another project, or update Android Studio, all of them are solutions recommended here. None of these have worked, I still get the same dreadful "ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN".

here's my java file

```
Button button;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

button= findViewById(R.id.button);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        System.out.print("Hello World");
    }
});
}
```

and my xml file

```
   `<FrameLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="243dp"
            android:text="Button" />
    </RelativeLayout></FrameLayout>
```

If anyone could please help me resolve this issue, it would be greatly appreciated. OnclickListener has always worked smoothly for me but for some reason, now I can't do the most basic of tasks. Help!

Answer (score 0):

Germain Edouard try to remove the backtick ` before the